# React TypeScriptにおいて、複数のコンポーネントをまとめる方法は？

Tags: reactjs, typescript

使用する際に、ComponentAll.Component1のように強制するにはどのような宣言方法を行えばよいのでしょうか？

---

component1.tsx

```
const Component1 = () => (
  <input type="email">
)
export default Component1;
```

component2.tsx

```
const Component2 = () => (
  <input type="password">
)
export default Component2;
```

component-all.ts

```
import Component1 from './Component1';
import Component2 from './Component2';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コンポーネントをexportする際に名前空間をつけたい、という趣旨でしょうか？
その場合は以下で可能だと思います。

```
// component-all.ts
export const ComponentAll = {
  Component1,
  Component2
};

// other-file.ts
import { ComponentAll } from './component-all';

ComponentAll.Component1;
```

[export | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export#using_named_exports)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。  

index.tsでまとめれることがわかりました。